# system() call NOT targeting a sub-shell?

Tags: c++, unix

Working on a C++ Unix program executed on the command line (MacOs).

I call `system("history -s SOMETHING")` in it to add `SOMETHING` to the history of the user's shell, but I guess the call is opening a new sub-shell.

My question is : can I execute the system call on the "current" shell (the one used to run the program) ?

To be clear I want to find the `SOMETHING` in my shell history when I quit the program.

Thanks !

Comment: You can't do that, and even if you could, your users would be very upset if you did.

Comment: Well this could be a feature of the program, and the user would be consentant (I am the user).
So it is NOT possible to target the "current" shell ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible in general.

If you're using bash, and since this is only for you:

Enable history appending in .bashrc:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

Launch a login bash shell in `main`:

```
system("bash -li -c 'history -s SOMETHING'");
```

and then refresh your history:

```
history -n
```

The `history -n` can be automated - you can execute it inside your prompt, for instance.
Figuring out how to do that left as an exercise.

(Disclaimer: I have only tried this in Ubuntu under the Windows Subsystem for Linux, but it should work very similarly on a Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.  The usual work around -- not applicable if there is other wanted output -- is to make your program prints the wanted command and then execute it.  For instance

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "history -s SOMETHING\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and then

```
eval $(/path/to/my/exe)
```

For ease of use, you can put that in a shell function

```
myfn() {
    eval $(/path/to/my/exe)
}
```

that you can simply use

```
myfn
```